# I cannot start a new project

Tags: jhipster

I wanted to test your project so I followed instructions listed here :

[Installing JHipster](http://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-app/)

[Creating an application](http://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-app/)

At the last step :

`yo jhipster`

I receive the error:

```
[08:23:27] Using gulpfile ~/dev/jhipster/itishipster/gulpfile.js
[08:23:27] Starting 'install'...
[08:23:27] Starting 'inject:test'...
[08:23:27] 'inject:test' errored after 11 ms
[08:23:27] Error: Bower components directory does not exist at /Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/src/main/webapp/bower_components
    at Error (native)
    at module.exports (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/main-bower-files/lib/index.js:76:17)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/gulpfile.js:130:31)
    at module.exports (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at runNextSet (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:88:16)
    at runSequence (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:99:2)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/gulpfile.js:234:5)
    at module.exports (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/ted/dev/jhipster/itishipster/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
[08:23:27] Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
Message:
    An error occured in task 'inject:test'.
[08:23:27] Finished 'install' after 16 ms
```

I try to start the project with maven command :

`./mvnw`

The console seems to be OK but I receive the error page:
 "An error has occured :-("

Any idea of the problem?

Comment: I have tested JHipster using docker and I have exactly the same error page : "An error has occured :-("

Answer (score 2):

Yes lots of ideas: I've written them all in the "An error has occured :-(" page, you should read it.

Comment: And did you have any errors? Have a look at your logs, it should be written there. That also varies depending on your OS, node version, etc etc, that's why you should also post them

Answer (score 1):

I will write some Commands here try to execute that before starting your new project,(Before that you have to install node.js)

1. npm install -g yo
2. npm install -g bower ( I think this may be the Problem for your above error)
3. npm install -g gulp
4. npm install -g generator-jhipster

Comment: Thank you Becky but after trying these commands I have the same problem. Do you know how I can activate a more verbose logging because I don't see anything in the console.

Comment: Yes and that's basically what is written in the error page -> but if you have some idea to improve it, please do!

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error. Here is what I have done to receive this error:

```
mkdir example-jhispster
cd example-jhipster
yo jhipster
mvn spring-boot:run
```

After that, I renamed the folder of project from `example-jhipster` to `example-jhipster2`. 
But I didn't terminate running instance.

From another terminal window I repeated above steps and got the same error.

Shortly speaking, you are probably running another instance from another terminat window. Close the running instance and try again.